# Build Error "LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors

So, I am a total noob at C++ and I need serious help. I bet for some average users this is not even a problem, so please help me.

I wrote this in Visual Studio Professional as a Win32 console file.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 100;

    return 0;
}
```

And in the console I get the following:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project1_RenatoAlegre, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 1/25/2012 3:09:03 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\Project1_RenatoAlegre.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>c:\users\ren\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Project1_RenatoAlegre\Debug\Project1_RenatoAlegre.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:03.37
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have no way of running the program because of this "1 failed" something. I must run the program in Visual Studio Professional.

Comment: Change your project settings to console application. Right now, you are trying to build GUI Windows application which requires `WinMain` as program-entry point, not `main`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Project properties -> C/C++ -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem: Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)

If you want a console project.

Answer (score 2):

Please change the `subsystem` in your linker settings from `Windows` to `Console`.

- Right click on the Project name in the `Solution Explorer`
- Select Properties
- Open Linker in Configuration Properties
- Subsystem will be the first item on the list.
- Select `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)` on the dropdown

Comment: Thank you very much, however the Subsystem item was inside the system item.